# Angular Templating ngIf with condition

Tags: angular

I have a div that i want it to disappear when two of my condition are null, at the moment it will display a blank div.

```
<div class="card statOf" *ngIf="selectedState._id">
        <div class="letter" *ngFor="let letter of letters">
            <div class="letter-user" *ngIf="letter.user">
                <span>
                    {{ letter.user }}</span>
                <div *ngIf="dateLastHeart">
                    <span>
                        {{ dateLastHeart }} </span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the moment it's working like i want when one of them is null, but when they are both null, it display the class card statOf, i want to hide it when they are both null, is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Your requirement is little unclear, the div with class `card statOf` is the container div for a loop. When you say both of them are null, they will be null for one loop instance right? or you don't want full div itself?

Comment: In my div i have that two span that i want to display, but when both of them are null i want to hide all that div

Comment: Specifically `null`? What about `undefined`, `''` or `0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about AND operator (... && ...). I can imagine something like this (I am not sure which variables are on your mind):

```
<div class="card statOf" *ngIf="selectedState && selectedState._id && letters && letters.length > 0">
  <div class="letter" *ngFor="let letter of letters">
     <div class="letter-user" *ngIf="letter.user">
        <span>{{ letter.user }}</span>
        <span *ngIf="dateLastHeart"> {{ dateLastHeart }} </span>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Edit

You don´t have access to "letter.user" on the outer div because it is out of the *ngFor scope. You could try to check if the letters array is empty.

```
<div class="card statOf" *ngIf="letters && letters.length > 0 && dateLastHeart">
  <div class="letter" *ngFor="let letter of letters">
     <div class="letter-user" *ngIf="letter.user">
        <span>{{ letter.user }}</span>
        <span>{{ dateLastHeart }} </span>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Edit

You say:

> i want it not be visible when BOTH OF THEM ARE NULL

*ngIf is a positive expresion that means: show something if ..condition..

So if you want to hide your container only when both of them are null the right expression is:

```
<container *ngIf="variableA || variableB"> ...
```

that means show me container only if variableA or variableB is set

Comment: that's displaying nothing even if they aren't null :/

Comment: Ah, i think i know what you are trying to do... you want the outer div to be visible only when "letter.user" and "dateLastHeart" are not null, right?

Comment: I want to hide it when both of them are null :D , because i'm getting it when one of them is not null or both of them aren't null. my problem is i get the div even if both of them are null

Comment: sorry that's not working, it's displaying nothing even if they aren't null :/ , don't forget i need my selectedState._id

Comment: @LisaNPMarie can you edit your post and show the whole HTML and TS file?

Comment: I just edited it, at the moment nothing changed i'm displaying the div even if letter.user is null or dateLast is null, my problem is that i want to hide that div when both of them are null.

Comment: @LisaNPMarie ah ok, try to change "&&" to "||" if you want that the card should be visible when one of the variable is set and then tell me if that worked. Like this:    *ngIf="(letters && letters.length > 0") ||  dateLastHeart>